# Rewrite rule not working on IIS with using Regex

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule in on Windows Server 6.2. Although I used IIS Manager to create the code, it didn't work.

I tried stopProcess true/false, used different regex, restart server several times. Nothing changed. I followed the whole steps on Microsoft's web site on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to e-campus" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="[^\/]+\/\/([^\/]+:?[0-9]?)\/.*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

I want to show only main URL. My domain is http://e-campus.example.com.

For example if someone go to that link: http://e-campus.example.com/Login/Student
Server should rewrite to this:
e-campus.example.com (with hiding http:// but it's not important)

So basically I just want to show main URL. But it keeps showing full path. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I found your regex match the whole url. But the iis url rewrite will not get the whole domain, it will just get the part of the url not the whole url.

For example:

If your url is `http://e-campus.example.com/Login/Student`., the match url part is 
 `login/Student`.

So if you want to rewrithe all the request to e-campus.example.com, you should use below url rewrite rule.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to e-campus" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://e-campus.example.com/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I checked but your regex also match full URL which is [link](http://e-campus.example.com/Login/Student). Anyway, I wrote exactly what you suggest, now whole web site on **404 fault**: When I go to [link](e-campus.example.com) or [link](e-campus.example.com/Login) etc, it gives me 404. Thank you for your answer, any other suggestion?

Comment: 404 means the page not found. If you directly access the http://e-campus.example.com/ without enabling the rewrite rule. Is it work well? Since I couldn't understand your requirement, I could just tell you what you wrong and give you a very easy simple. I suggest you could post more details information about what your requirement about url rewrite rule.